# cakephp xml parser

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am parsing cakephp using xml parser. It parses it just fine. Its a huge xml. I now need to enter that into a database. Any easy way to do it without going into too much trouble with all those arrays and sub arrays

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on what the array looks like and how you want to store the data. If you just need to capture the array, you can use serialize:

```
$data = serialize($xml_array)
```

And store that in a text field.

If you need to store each item in the array, you can do that easy enough as long as there are not sub-arrays within the array. If it is for example and array like this:

```
array(
  [MyArray] => (
     [Field1] => 'data',
     [field2] => 'data',
  )
)
```

and the Field1 and field2 match the columns of the table, just change `[MyArray]` to the model name and pass the array to the `model->save()` function and it will save the data.

However, if you have sub-array information:

```
array(
  [MyArray] => (
     [Field1] => array([sub_array] => 'more_data'),
     [field2] => 'data',
  )
)
```

Your only option is to parse the data into an array that can be saved and then save it.